# How to properly make vertical bars with CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make some vertical bars using borders in CSS. I am using a Boostrap web page system and I am trying to add a left and right border to certain columns.  The problems come in when a certain column in a row (one without the border) is taller than the column than the one with the border.  The border becomes fragmented with blank white space in between the rows like below in ascii:

```
content |         some text in a row
content |         that keeps
content |         on going
blank             and going
blank             and going
blank             and going
content |         some text in a different row
content |         that goes up to here
```

EDIT:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3" style='border-left: 1px solid black; border-right: 1px solid black;'>
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    ... (Stuff here is vertically taller than stuff in previous column)
  </div>
</div>
```

Pretend that the `|` are connecting and there  is a gap between these sections.  How can I solve this problem?

Comment: post your CSS please

Comment: yes, a full snippet would make things easier

Comment: Posted a sample of the HTML

Answer (score 0):

[Read all you ever need to know about faux columns](http://alistapart.com/article/fauxcolumns).

Management summary: put a vertically tiled background on the parent element, thus giving the **illusion** that both elements are of equal height. The most important lesson you'll ever learn about CSS is that it's just a presentational tool, and doesn't need to correspond in any way to your *actual* layout.

If old browsers are [of no concern](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) just use [flexbox](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) instead.